# Android AlertDialog and cursors

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-cursor

I've built an AlertDialog using a cursor to populate the list items in the dialog.  All works well with creating the list.

I even get the 'which' item back in the callback for the row selected.  One problem remains...

How do I get the text back for the item that was clicked???

I don't want to requery the cursor and spin through the results getting to the 'which' item but I don't know how else to get the value.

Thanks

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_GENUS_LIST_CURSOR:
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(AquaNotesDbContract.Genus.CONTENT_URI,
                    GenusQuery.PROJECTION, null, null, null);
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(Gallery.this)
                        .setTitle(Res.string.select_genus)
                        .setCursor(cursor,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    /* an item was selected */  
                            < this is where I want to learn the text selected??? >                  
                            }
                        },
                    GenusQuery.PROJECTION[GenusQuery.COMMON_NAME])
                        .create();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about in the onClick handler...

```
cursor.moveToPosition(which);
cursor.getString(GenusQuery.PROJECTION.INDEX_OF_COLUMN_OF_TEXT_YOU_WANT);
```

Comment: That works great, thank you.  I  think I got messed up by a scope error the first time I tried something like that.  All I had to do to make your solution work was define the cursor as 'final'.